# HTTPS request in nsi script

Tags: https, nsis

Is it possible to perform an HTTPS request to my domain using a .nsi script for NULLsoft?

I've tried to use NSISdl::download_quiet /TIMEOUT=50000 "hxxps://example.org" "C:\Users\me\Desktop\config.ini" but seems that it doesn't work...

Does InetC support this? I've tried it but with no result...

Comment: What does no result mean? A error message?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [INetC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) uses the same web library as Internet Explorer and it supports HTTPS.

```
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Section
CreateDirectory $InstDir
inetc::get "https://example.com/myfile.ext" "$InstDir\myfile.ext" /END
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0 ; "OK" if successful
SectionEnd
```

You can add the `/WEAKSECURITY` switch if the server is using outdated SSL certificates.

Comment: Great, thank you Anders! One last question: what is the difference between the ansi dll and the unicode one? I mean, if I use the x86-unicode the request doesn't shots, while using the x86-ansi it works like a charm. Any idea about this strange behavior?

Comment: The NSIS Unicode target and plug-in type must match. Not all plug-ins have a Unicode version.